# object positions are being outputted instead of INT values | Python based interpreter

Tags: python, integer, interpreter

I was adding some error handling and along the way the interpreter stopped outputting ints and outputted object positions like `<basic.ParseResult object at 0x0000005EA2521510>`, it also started ignoring `"*" MUL` and `"/" DIV` again...
I suspect the problem is caused by string_with_arrows.py or parse result

```
###############################################################################################
#   IMPORT
###############################################################################################

from string_with_arrows import *

###############################################################################################
#   CONSTANTS
###############################################################################################

DIGITS = '0123456789'

###############################################################################################
#   ERRORS
###############################################################################################

class Error:
    def __init__(self, pos_start, pos_end, error_name, details):
        self.pos_start  = pos_start
        self.pos_end    = pos_end
        self.error_name = error_name
        self.details    = details
    
    def as_string(self):
        result          = f'{self.error_name}: {self.details}'
        result         += f'File {self.pos_start.fn}, line {self.pos_start.ln + 1}'
        result         += '\n\n' + string_with_arrows(self.pos_start.ftxt, self.pos_start, self.pos_end)
        return result

class IllegalCharError(Error):
    def __init__(self, pos_start, pos_end, details):
        super().__init__(pos_start, pos_end, 'Illegal character', details)

class InvalidSyntaxError(Error):
    def __init__(self, pos_start, pos_end, details=''):
        super().__init__(pos_start, pos_end, 'Invalid Syntax', details)
    
###############################################################################################
#   POSITION
###############################################################################################

class Position:
    def __init__(self, idx, ln, col, fn, ftxt):
        self.idx  = idx
        self.ln   = ln
        self.col  = col
        self.fn   = fn
        self.ftxt = ftxt

    def advance(self, current_char=None):
        self.idx += 1
        self.col += 1

        if current_char == '\n':
            self.ln += 1
            self.col = 0
        
        return self
    
    def copy(self):
        return Position(self.idx, self.ln, self.col, self.fn, self.ftxt)

###############################################################################################
#   TOKENS
###############################################################################################

TT_INT      = 'INT'
TT_FLOAT    = 'FLOAT'
TT_PLUS     = 'PLUS'
TT_MINUS    = 'MINUS'
TT_MUL      = 'MUL'
TT_DIV      = 'DIV'
TT_LPAREN   = 'LPAREN'
TT_RPAREN   = 'RPAREN'
TT_EOF      = 'EOF'

class Token:
    def __init__(self, type_, value=None, pos_start=None, pos_end=None):
        self.type = type_
        self.value = value

        if pos_start:
            self.pos_start = pos_start.copy()
            self.pos_end   = pos_start.copy()
            self.pos_end.advance()

        if pos_end:
            self.pos_end   = pos_end

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.value: return f'{self.type}:{self.value}'
        return f'{self.type}'
    
###############################################################################################
#   LEXER
###############################################################################################

class Lexer:
    def __init__(self, fn, text):
        self.fn           = fn
        self.text         = text
        self.pos          = Position(-1, 0, -1, fn, text)
        self.current_char = None
        self.advance()
    
    def advance(self):
        self.pos.advance(self.current_char)
        self.current_char = self.text[self.pos.idx] if self.pos.idx < len(self.text) else None

    def make_tokens(self):
        tokens            = []

        while self.current_char != None:
            if self.current_char in ' \t':
                self.advance()
            elif self.current_char in DIGITS:
                tokens.append(self.make_number())
            elif self.current_char == '+':
                tokens.append(Token(TT_PLUS, pos_start=self.pos))
                self.advance()
            elif self.current_char == '-':
                tokens.append(Token(TT_MINUS, pos_start=self.pos))
                self.advance()
            elif self.current_char == '*':
                tokens.append(Token(TT_MUL, pos_start=self.pos))
                self.advance()
            elif self.current_char == '/':
                tokens.append(Token(TT_DIV, pos_start=self.pos))
                self.advance()
            elif self.current_char == '(':
                tokens.append(Token(TT_LPAREN, pos_start=self.pos))
                self.advance()
            elif self.current_char == ')':
                tokens.append(Token(TT_RPAREN, pos_start=self.pos))
                self.advance()
            else:
            ###################################
            #         ERROR HANDLING          #
            ###################################
                pos_start = self.pos.copy()
                char = self.current_char
                self.advance()
                return [], IllegalCharError(pos_start, self.pos, "'" + char + "'")
            
        tokens.append(Token(TT_EOF, pos_start=self.pos))
        return tokens, None
    
    def make_number(self):
        num_str     = ''
        dot_count   = 0
        pos_start   = self.pos.copy()

        while self.current_char != None and self.current_char in DIGITS + '.':
            if self.current_char == '.':
                if dot_count == 1:
                    break
                dot_count += 1
                num_str   += '.'
            else:
                num_str   += self.current_char
            self.advance()
        
        if dot_count == 0:
            return Token(TT_INT, int(num_str), pos_start, self.pos)
        else:
            return Token(TT_FLOAT, float(num_str), pos_start, self.pos)
        
###############################################################################################
#   NODES
###############################################################################################

class NumberNode:
    def __init__(self, tok):
        self.tok = tok

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.tok}'

class BinOpNode:
    def __init__(self, left_node, op_tok, right_node):
        self.left_node  = left_node
        self.op_tok     = op_tok
        self.right_node = right_node

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'({self.left_node}, {self.op_tok}, {self.right_node})'
    
###############################################################################################
#   PARSE RESULT
###############################################################################################

class ParseResult:
    def __init__(self):
        self.error = None
        self.node  = None
    
    def register(self, res):
        if isinstance(res, ParseResult):
            if res.error:
                self.error = res.error
                return res.node
            
            return res

    def success(self, node):
        self.node = node
        return self

    def failure(self, error):
        self.error = error
        return self

###############################################################################################
#   PARSER
###############################################################################################

class Parser:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens      = tokens
        self.tok_idx     = -1
        self.advance()
    
    def advance(self):
        self.tok_idx += 1
        if self.tok_idx < len(self.tokens):
            self.current_tok = self.tokens[self.tok_idx]

        return self.current_tok
    
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ #

    def parse(self):
        res = self.expr()
        if not res.error and self.current_tok.type != TT_EOF:
            return res.failure(InvalidSyntaxError(self.current_tok.pos_start, 
            self.current_tok.pos_end, "Expected '+', '-', '*' or '/'"))
        return res
    
    def factor(self):
        res = ParseResult()
        tok = self.current_tok

        if tok.type in (TT_INT, TT_FLOAT):
            res.register(self.advance())
            return res.success(NumberNode(tok))
        
        return res.failure(InvalidSyntaxError(tok.pos_start, 
        tok.pos_end, "Expected int or float"))

    def term(self):
        return self.bin_op(self.factor, (TT_MUL, TT_DIV))

    def expr(self):
        return self.bin_op(self.term, (TT_PLUS, TT_MINUS))
    
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ #

    def bin_op(self, func, ops):
        res  = ParseResult()
        left = res.register(func())
        if res.error:
            return res

        while self.current_tok.type in ops:
            op_tok = self.current_tok
            res.register(self.advance())
            right  = res.register(func())
            if res.error:
                return res
            left   = BinOpNode(left, op_tok, right)

        return res.success(left)

###############################################################################################
#   RUN
###############################################################################################

def run(fn, text):

    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ #
    #                   TOKEN GENERATOR                    #
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ #

    lexer         = Lexer(fn, text)
    tokens, error = lexer.make_tokens()

    if error:
        return None, error

    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ #
    #                     GENERATE AST                     #
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ #
    # VOCAB 1: AST: Abstract Syntax Tree

    parser = Parser(tokens)
    ast    = parser.parse()

    return ast.node, ast.error
```

```
def string_with_arrows(text, pos_start, pos_end):
    result = ''

    # Calculate indices
    idx_start = max(text.rfind('\n', 0, pos_start.idx), 0)
    idx_end = text.find('\n', idx_start + 1)
    if idx_end < 0: idx_end = len(text)
    
    # Generate each line
    line_count = pos_end.ln - pos_start.ln + 1
    for i in range(line_count):
        # Calculate line columns
        line = text[idx_start:idx_end]
        col_start = pos_start.col if i == 0 else 0
        col_end = pos_end.col if i == line_count - 1 else len(line) - 1

        # Append to result
        result += line + '\n'
        result += ' ' * col_start + '^' * (col_end - col_start)

        # Re-calculate indices
        idx_start = idx_end
        idx_end = text.find('\n', idx_start + 1)
        if idx_end < 0: idx_end = len(text)

    return result.replace('\t', '')
```

```
import basic

while True:
    text = input('SOS > ')
    result, error = basic.run('<stdin>', text)

    if error:
        print(error.as_string())
    else:
        print(result)
```

```
expr     : term ((PLUS|MINUS) term)*

term     : factor ((MUL|DIV) factor)*

factor   : INT|FLOAT
```

```
PS C:\Users\essam\Desktop\spl> & "C:/Program Files/Python311/python.exe" c:/Users/essam/Desktop/spl/shell.py
SOS > t
Illegal character: 't'File <stdin>, line 1

t
^
SOS > 5 + 5
(<basic.ParseResult object at 0x0000005EA2521510>, PLUS, <basic.ParseResult object at 0x0000005EA25215D0>)
SOS > 5 +
Invalid Syntax: Expected in or floatFile <stdin>, line 1

5 +
   ^
SOS > 5 + 5 / 6
(<basic.ParseResult object at 0x0000005EA2521890>, PLUS, <basic.ParseResult object at 0x0000005EA2521990>)
SOS >
```

Comment: Give your `ParseResult` class `__repr__` and `__str__` methods as shown in the linked duplicate so that you can get the result that you want when an instance appears inside a container like a tuple.